# GZIPInputStream .read() limitations

Tags: java, base64, gzip, compression

I am trying to use GZIPInputStream in Java to decompress image data coming from my .NET application (which compresses in GZIP format). The image data is transferred as base64 strings because it is synced over as XML text. I was under the assumption that the stream would read into the buffer passed into .read() parameters until the buffer was saturated. It is not working as I had expected, i.e., the .read() only reads let's say, 800 or so bytes per read operation. This is not a problem for small images but for big ones, like 800 KB it takes a very long time to decompress. I have written a small test sample to showcase this:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;
import java.util.zip.GZIPOutputStream;

public class GZIPtest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String b64img = "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";
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);
    gzos.write(b64img.getBytes());
    gzos.close();

    byte[] compressed = bos.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed);
    GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bis);
    int bufSize = 8192;
    byte[] decompressed = new byte[bufSize];
    int read = gzis.read(decompressed);
    String s = new String(decompressed, 0, read);
    while (read != -1) {
        decompressed = new byte[bufSize];
        read = gzis.read(decompressed);
        String tmp = "";
        if (read != -1) {
            tmp = new String(decompressed, 0, read);
            s += tmp;
        }
    }
    gzis.close();
    if (b64img.equals(s))
        System.out.print("EQUAL");
    System.exit(0);
}

}
```

`b64img` is the base64 representation of [this image](https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/3691/bath_bathroom_pipe_toilet_icon#size=64). It is a simple 6 KB image, so running this program shouldn't take very long. If you step through the read process you will see that it does not saturate the `decompressed` byte buffer.

I used the print statement to see if the compressed/decompressed strings were equal, as my own test to see if GZIP was working properly.

Comment: I think you need to decode the base64 first, then decompress the results

Comment: This might be because [the default buffer size for the inflater stream (link)](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.java#GZIPInputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28java.io.InputStream%29) is 512. You may want to specify a higher value like, 'GZIPInputStream(in, 4096)'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[srkavin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/862441/srkavin) is correct. You can set the buffer size with the constructor of the GZIPInputStream.